# how to disply current time in Cprogram, compiling in CodeVisionAVR

Tags: c

I am trying to display current time in C program. I am using CodeVisionAVR compiler.
I have the fallowing code

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <delay.h>

void continious(viod)
 {
 time_t now;
 time(&now);
 printf("%s", ctime(&now));

 ------------
 --------------
 }

 void runtime(viod)
 {
  unsigned char c; 
        c=getchar();      
    switch(C){
        case '1':
              continious();
        case '2':
        -----
        default:
     }

 int main (void){
       while (1){

        if(rx_counter0) runCom(); 
       }
      }
```

the above code is executing normally before adding time function now i want to include current time so i have tried like that. I want to display current time when i enter CASE'1'. I have tried the above code but the problem is i am getting 
error like

> Can't open #include file: time.h

Please any one suggest me how can overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

You are programming for an embedded platform, whose libraries don't include `time.h`. There probably isn't any guaranteed clock on the platform, either.

You need to investigate what your hardware and libraries support, or implement the relevant functionality on your own.

Comment: @unwind I am working on ATmega32-A microcontroller. I am programming in C. Do you have any idea how to include time.

Answer (score 0):

check out with **TIME** Its a macro constant. It works in C compilers for computers I am not sure for embedded system.

```
int main(){
    printf("%s",__TIME__);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more details, if possible some example.